# Determine if an element will animate via a CSS3 transition

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm in need of a light weight solution to determine if any elements will animate (using any [animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)) when specific classes are applied to their parent.

The [following code](http://jsbin.com/nicor/1/edit?html,css,output) sets up an element that will animate when `<div id="parent">` is given a class of `step1`.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="box">Box</div>
</div>

.box {
  border: red solid 1px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
}

#parent.step1 .box {
  transform: translate(0, 100px);
}
```

On document ready, I need to determine whether the element will animate when it is given a class of `step1`, `step2`, and so on. My current solution is as follows:

1. Clone the parent element
2. Get *all* CSS properties applied to the child element as JSON
3. Convert the JSON properties to a single string
4. Add the class of `step1` to the parent
5. Repeat step 2 and 3 to get the child's properties in a string again
6. Compare the strings - If the strings differ (the properties have changed) and the element is subject to a `transition-duration`, I can assume a transition will occur.

This current solution *works* but is very bad performance. Getting all CSS properties for an element consists of looping through every single property and getting its computed value. What's more, I want to be able to determine if many elements will animate. I've tested with a parent element consisting of 30 elements and this current solution takes around 3 seconds to execute (so obviously not a solution at all).

Note that multiple class names will be applied to the parent (`step1`, `step2`, and so on) and that I have applied `transition-duration` globally to `.box`. This means I can't just determine the element will animate based on it having a `transition-duration` because it can have a `transition-duration` but not yet be transitioning.

For the potential solution to work, I don't want to limit how the CSS is written in anyway. Looking at the element to see if it has a `transition-duration` would work if the `transition-duration` were specified under `#parent.step1 .box {}` but not as it is, with the `transition-duration` specified globally to any `.box`.

Finally, getting the stylesheet and reading from it directly is not an option either. This adds layers of complexity when using regex and stylesheets can not always be retrived due to cross-domain policy etc.

Update: I've also tried to apply a `transition-duration` of `5ms` to the element, set up a `transitionend` event and then apply the class of `step1` to the parent. A timer runs for `5ms` until the next class of `step2` is applied to the parent. If the element's 5ms transition finishes before the timer is up and the next class is applied, I know what step it belongs to. The problem with this attempted solution is that because I'm working with such small time periods, the timer is unreliable. Even if I make the timer run every `10ms`, the element can still sometimes take longer to finish transitioning.

Comment: Why can't you check for `transform` CSS property for a given element when the class is applied?

Comment: The solution needs to determine when the element will transition using *any* property. I'll update the question to specify that.

Comment: Specify all possible animated properties in the array and check for "if exists" then.

Comment: @VisioN This reduces the number of loops but with over 100 animatable properties, it's still very heavy on performance.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just using a feature detection tool like [`Modernizr`](http://modernizr.com/) to check if the browser supports the `transform` property? You can customize it to detect just the features you want to know about and, after the page loaded, you need just to check if the `html` has a specific class to know whether you can use a feature or not.

Comment: The point is not to test if an element *can* animate based on browser support, but if it will when a class is applied to the parent element.